# Zurb Foundation Nav has Limited Style in Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 3 via the zurb-foundation gem on a rails project. Everything is going well until I've tried to add a navigation bar:

```
<body>
  <div id="container" class="twelve columns">
      <div class="fixed contain-to-grid">
        <nav class="top-bar">
          <ul>
            <li class="name"><h1><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></h1></li>
          </ul>
          <section>
            <ul class="left">
              <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Which looks like:

[image: Zurb Nav Appearance]

I have not override any of the zurb styling except for the colors, my assumption is that it would appear pretty similar to the first example in the documentation http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php but that does not seem to be the case. The documentation also mentions the javascript dependancies, but those are being included.

Anyone have any ideas on how to start get this to start looking pretty?

EDIT:

Adding the line to the first list like so:

```
<ul>
            <li class="name"><h1><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></h1></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
```

Renders this:

[image: After first suggestion]

Inspecting the element to see if things are display, the navigation JS is there:

```
(function ($){

  $.fn.foundationNavigation = function (options) {

    var lockNavBar = false;
    // Windows Phone, sadly, does not register touch events :(
    if (Modernizr.touch || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
      $(document).on('click.fndtn touchstart.fndtn', '.nav-bar a.flyout-toggle', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var flyout = $(this).siblings('.flyout').first();
        if (lockNavBar === false) {
          $('.nav-bar .flyout').not(flyout).slideUp(500);
          flyout.slideToggle(500, function () {
            lockNavBar = false;
          });
        }
        lockNavBar = true;
      });
      $('.nav-bar>li.has-flyout', this).addClass('is-touch');
    } else {
      $('.nav-bar>li.has-flyout', this).hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.flyout').show();
      }, function () {
        $(this).children('.flyout').hide();
      });
    }

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Looking for the css from foundation, it is working for buttons and everything, and the nav bar styles seem to be there as well, for example:

```
.nav-bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the element and verify that the styles are being applied? It looks to me like the CSS is completely missing for the navigation elements.

Comment: There are two navigation bars in foundation Top Bar and Nav Bar. You are implementing the Top Bar, however the code you posted from inspecting the source shows the Nav Bar js/css. Is there any way to give a direct link to your site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you with zurb-foundation 3.0.9. Try upgrade to 3.1.1

In your Gemfile, use:

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 3.1.1'
```

And in application.scss:

```
@import 'foundation';
```

Make sure you have this in document ready

```
$(document).foundationTopBar();
```

Update Gems

```
bundle update
```

Make sure cache is removed:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this line after the first list item

`<li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>`

That's probably what's going on, but not 100% positive.

Answer (score 0):

You should place something like this example below, above all of your `<div>` tags and below the `<body>` tag. It exists outside of the grid system so it should be above everything. Notice there are no `<div>` tags.

```
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">James Stone</a></h1></li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section>
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">I</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </section>
  </nav>
```